# I need Collectionview cell autoresized. if data is available show on cell else auto set cell

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview, autoresize

I m making social feed type post using collection view. but problem is that . i cannot setup cell if image available then cell size stretch else image not available auto resize cell.Thank you

Comment: you have to set proper `constraint` it'll be manage it self. Share screen shot of cell design with it's `constraints` screen shot.

Comment: okay thank you dear,can it done with IGlistkit library?